# Aligning text in input text field little further away to the right

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYzGF.jpg)

How can I align my placeholder text toward the right side? Please help!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Should the text be on the right too?

Answer (score 2):

You can use text-align:right;

```css
input{
text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="User">
```